# Cannot get 'default' Apache VirtualHost to work

Tags: configuration, apache2, virtualhost

I've changed this from the original VHost but it should still work in my mind:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 ServerAdmin ross@localhost

 DocumentRoot /var/www
 <Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

 # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
 # alert, emerg.
 LogLevel warn

 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The only difference between this and other working VHosts is that /var/www requires higher privileges to access it - I get a "Could not connect" error which I assume is a 500 error (Chrome hides the status codes and I can't remember). What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Error 500 means, that connect to Apache is working, but something behind it does not.

What can you see in /var/log/apache2/error.log after trying to see the page?

Comment: Use `wget -S hostname` to see the real errorcode it returns all the headers. Or you can press Ctrl+u in chrome on the error page to see the html sent from apache if any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try performing a manual connection using telnet from a terminal window:

```
telnet localhost 80
```

If you receive a `connection refused` message, the daemon is not running or starting up propertly. From there it would be a good idea to inspect your Apache error log (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`) to find out why.

Answer (score 1):

Could not connect is not a 500 error. It means apache is either not running or not reachable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but I think Apache runs as the www-user login, or similar.  Does it have rights to the root of /var/www?  I think by default, Apache points to symlinks off an /etc/apache2/default directory or something like that.  Working from memory here, and no expert though.  Sorry.